# Cannot get property from object $this variable

Tags: php, undefined, phpactiverecord

I really confused with the situation. I want to get data from function in my class, that created by ActiveRecord Model. Here a class:

```
class Bag extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $table_name = "bags";
    static $primary_key = 'bag_id';

    public function get_pocket_types() {
        $arr = json_decode($this->pocket_types);
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

I call it in my main code:

```
$bag = Bag::find_by_bag_id((int)$_GET['id']);
$types = $bag->get_pocket_types();
```

It seems to be good, but I have an error `Notice: Undefined property: Bag::$pocket_types in models/Bag.php on line 21` when I try to get `$this->pocket_types`. This field is absolutely exists, like a field `bag_id`.

I've even tried to debug it (in function get_pocket_types() ):

```
echo $this->bag_id;
// OK

echo $this->bag_id_NOT_EXISTS;
// Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\UndefinedPropertyException' with message 'Undefined property: Bag->bag_id_NOT_EXISTS
// This is just for catch an error of REALLY not existed field

echo $this->pocket_types;
// Notice: Undefined property: Bag::$pocket_types in models/Bag.php on line 21
```

I called `var_dump($this);` in the function:

> object(Bag)#16 (6) {   ["errors"]=>   NULL
>   ["attributes":"ActiveRecord\Model":private]=>   array(2) {
>       ["bag_id"]=>
>       int(160)
>       ["pocket_types"]=>
>       string(0) ""   }   ["__dirty":"ActiveRecord\Model":private]=>   array(0) {   }   ["__readonly":"ActiveRecord\Model":private]=>
>   bool(false)   ["__relationships":"ActiveRecord\Model":private]=>
>   array(0) {   }   ["__new_record":"ActiveRecord\Model":private]=>
>   bool(false) }

Somebody can explain what happens please?

Comment: My guess is that the problem is the variable scope. If `pocket_types` is private on the parent class then you can't access it

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou I'm getting `pocket_types` from the same class (`Bag`) function... I can get `bag_id` there! But I cannot get `pocket_type`. Unbelievable

Comment: Can you update your code with the full Class definition?

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou it's full class definition code. I've delete all other code to debug, but I get an error anyway

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou it's created automatically with Activerecord\Model (ORM) from a database

Comment: can we see your Model class? I feel like Dimitris is on the money that the var scope is off. It's not a property in your Bag class so it doesn't exist there.. so it either is private in your Model or it's not a property in your Model

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, it's not _his_ [Model class](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/Model.php)

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski ah I see haha :p

Comment: @RyanVincent, no why? I already fixed problem, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have created a [custom getter with the same name as an attribute](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Model#method__get).

In which case you will need `$this->read_attribute('pocket_types')` instead of `$this->pocket_types`

Or, rename `get_pocket_types` to something like `get_json_decoded_pocket_types`.

Comment: Yes, I checked documentation and realize it too, thanks. But it's strange - when I try to `$this->read_attribute('pocket_types')` there, I also get an error: `Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\UndefinedPropertyException' with message 'Undefined property: Bag->pocket_type in ...Bag.php(7): ActiveRecord\Model->read_attribute('pocket_type')`... damned php.activerecords :) Maybe another name of function is the best solution for the situation

Comment: It's `pocket_types` not `pocket_type` no?

Comment: ohhh, yes, my mistake here) now It's worked, thanks again!